# How to change the color for keywords: public, static, boolean, return?

Tags: intellij-idea

i went to preferences, Editor, Color Scheme, Language Defaults.
In Keywords, i changed the color.
Restart Intellij, but color didn't change.

Any suggestions ?
Thx !

Comment: The setting you've mentioned works fine for me. Are you editing Java code? It could be that Java code style is not inherited from the defaults, you can [double check it here](https://i.imgur.com/btmivNj.png).

Comment: You are right, many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that Java code style is not inherited from the defaults, you can [double check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347GP.png).